# Set Up OpenVPN with Ldap support on CentOS7

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openvpn, centos7

We are trying to set up OpenVPN with ldap support via openvpn-auth-ldap on CentOS7.

The EPEL repository is not listing openvpn-auth-ldap anymore for [CentOS7](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/letter_o.group.html). For [CentOS6](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/openvpn-auth-ldap.html), there was a working relase.

We can not find any working release for CentOS7. The earlier builds won't run. They result in missing dependencies, etc. We did not find a solution on the web, thats why we ask here.

Is there a solution with an alternative plugin for openvpn or do we need to downgrade to CentOS6?

Comment: Not sure why this isn't being built. You could always ask the maintainer, or grab the [source RPM](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=5967) and rebuild it for EL7 yourself, e.g. in Copr?

Comment: Asking the maintainer is a good idea. Can systemd  be a Problem? They switched with version 7. The source repo does'nt seem to get a lot of attention.

Comment: We solved this now by switching to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The module is available there and it works without problems. So the question is still valid, but sadly not important for us anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: This is in EPEL for EL7. Avoid my Copr listed below, as I've backported some security fixes into EPEL that aren't in the Copr.

I was able to take the [openvpn-auth-ldap-2.0.3-14.fc21](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=503701) SRPM and make a few *really* minor tweaks to update it for the current version of OpenVPN, which makes use of a new plugin version. I've tested it on CentOS 7 with OpenVPN 2.3.10-1 (installed from EPEL) and it seems to be working properly.

While I'm reaching out to people about getting it in EPEL, it is available on [my Copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/seancallaway/openvpn-auth-ldap/).